# Composite key vs Composite column in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, hector

I want to know where and when to use composite column and composite key in Cassandr

Answer (score 2):

Composite-key usage can be useful in many scenario.

Imagine a table **users** in which you have a user id (uuid) as primary key (single-key)
You can't query this table unless you know the id of the user (ignore secondary indexes at the moment).

Now let's consider a table in which you doesn't use anymore the id as primary key, but you use a composite key made of **(name, surname, email)**

Now you can query your users by knowing

name
name - surname
name - surname - emails

primary key must be unique and in this scenario the email should guarantee that the user is unique. **Take care, to query by email you must know both name and surname, to query for the surname you must know the name** (this is true unless you don't use a particular way to model yours data).

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  name text,
  surname text,
  email text,
  age int,
  address text,
  id uuid,
  PRIMARY KEY (name, surname, email)
)
```

Another useful scenario can be for data-sorting.
Imagine you have a table in which you keep tweets (identified by a time uuid) made from a tweeter (identified by a uuid).

In cassandra the first part of the key is known as Partition key, the remaining is known as clustering key. For the same partition key data can be sorted by a clustering key

```
CREATE TABLE tweets (
  tweeter_id uuid,
  tweet_id timeuuid,
  content text,
  PRIMARY KEY (tweeter_id, tweet_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (tweet_id DESC)
```

In this scenario once you ask cassandra the tweets made by a tweeter they will be time-sorted for free.

Cheers,
Carlo

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what about composite column?

Comment: In the new Cassandra 2.1 composite columns will be used to store user-defined type. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5590